# Reading Json files in Spark and filter them out by ID

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following small app in Spark:

```
public class ReadAndFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String path = "D:\\file.json";
        String outputPath = "D:\\outputSparkTest";

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "D:\\hadoop");

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("ReadAndFilter");
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(ctx);

        DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(path).sqlContext().sql("SELECT * WHERE id = 8909");
        df.save(outputPath);
        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```

I am returned with this error:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Lscala/Function0;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.InferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(InferSchema.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.InferSchema$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(InferSchema.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:201)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$23.apply(RDD.scala:1103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1$$anonfun$24.apply(RDD.scala:1104)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong, can you spot an issue with my code? Do I need to serialise the Json file before reading it into the sqlContext? The file has the following format:

```
{"id":8909, "anotherfield": "Test"}
{"id":2809, "anotherfield2": "Test2"}
 ...
```

Could this be because of its internal format?

Thanks for your help,

I.

Comment: I ran your code and it works well except that you have to register temp table before selecting datas. Since error stack gives `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` maybe it's a problem with build path or something

Comment: You could separate the data loading and sql query to check in which step it fails: `DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().json(path);` and then `df.registerTempTable("tmp"); DataFrame newDF = df.sqlContext().sql("SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id = 8909");`

Comment: @Yuan JI, thanks for this, much appreciated. I was missing the temp table.